# make the Image a percentage of the screen and not pixels?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, web

For my web development class I have 3 images, one when clicked on the image starts the race and the other two will race across the screen. On my PC at home the images are laid out on the screen almost perfect, and when the racing images get to the end they will go over the image that starts it. At school the images that move across the screen will not go over the image that starts it because it is higher up and the other two images are smaller, since its in pixels. How can I get the image that starts the race to make it almost half screen size, and the two other images when since they are on top of each other, they will almost be about half size?

I do have JavaScript code but that is just to get the images to move

Here is the body images

```
<body>
<div id="location" class="clickme">
<input type="image" id="start" src="death.png" alt="dstar"  onclick="startRace()" class="img3">
</div>
<div class="raceTrack">
<img src="tie.png" id="1" alt="tie" class="img1">
<hr>
<img src="xwing.png" id="x-wing" alt="xwing" class="img2">
</div>
<div id="announce" class="hidden">
<span id="message">and the winner is...</span>
<img id="winner" src="1.png" alt="x-wing.png" >
</div>
</body>
```

Here is the Style Code

```
<style>
body { 
background-image: url(home.png); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
}
div.raceTrack {
position: fixed;
margin: auto;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
}
div#location{
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
}
img {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
transition: all 0.2s;
}
div#announce {
position: fixed;
margin: auto;
top: 0px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 10em;
width: 10em;
text-align: center;
transition: all 0.5s;
}
.hidden {
opacity: 0;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use relative units in your CSS.

The `%` are relative to the parent (or closest fixed unit)

The `vh` and `vw` are from 0 to 100 and represent the viewport (window size)

So:

```
<div style="width: 500px;">
    <div style="width: 50%">This will be 50% of 500px</div>
    <div style="width: 50vw;">This will be 50% of window width</div>
</div>
```

Using `vh` (viewport height) and `vw` (viewport width) will also automatically adjust if the window is resized.

Comment: so in the body within the div of the images I should add the <div style="width: number%"></div>

Comment: and the <div style="width: 50vw;";</div>  ?? and do nothing to the style part of the code?

Comment: never mind those comments. I figured it out. #Simonrules